# I'm having trouble downloading allennlp ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch<1.6.0,>=1.5.0

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, allennlp

when I try to download `pip install allennlp==1.0.0 allennlp-models==1.0.`

I am facing this problem :

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.469]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ahmad Sadek>pip install allennlp==1.0.0 allennlp-models==1.0.0
Collecting allennlp==1.0.0
  Using cached allennlp-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (473 kB)
Collecting allennlp-models==1.0.0
  Using cached allennlp_models-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (282 kB)
Collecting tqdm>=4.19
  Using cached tqdm-4.62.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (76 kB)
Collecting jsonpickle
  Using cached jsonpickle-2.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (38 kB)
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 (from allennlp) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch<1.6.0,>=1.5.0
```

What should I do?

I am using Python 3.10.2
win 11 pro

Comment: Try installing PyTorch 1.5 first using these instructions: https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/#v150

Answer (score 0):

You can install PyTorch previous versions from this link [PyTorch previous versions](https://pytorch.org/get-started/previous-versions/)

Example:

## CUDA 9.2

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cudatoolkit=9.2 -c pytorch
```

## CUDA 10.1

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cudatoolkit=10.1 -c pytorch
```

## CUDA 10.2

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cudatoolkit=10.2 -c pytorch
```

## CPU Only

```
conda install pytorch==1.5.0 torchvision==0.6.0 cpuonly -c pytorch
```